# How to reference the right object in Unity

Tags: unity, physics, raycasting

So, I'm developing this small 2D project where I have a sphere that detects if objects get close to it from three different directions.

[image]

I have successfully found a way to detect if an object touches my line if the object is referenced to a certain `LayerMask`, in this case the walls.

So, basically I'm doing this:

```
var layerMask = 1 << 10; //wall layer
float left = 0f, middle = 0f, right = 0f;

Debug.DrawLine (leftStart.position, leftEnd.position, Color.green);
Debug.DrawLine (middleStart.position, middleEnd.position, Color.green);
Debug.DrawLine (rightStart.position, rightEnd.position, Color.green);

leftSpot = Physics2D.Linecast(leftStart.position, leftEnd.position, layerMask);
middleSpot = Physics2D.Linecast(middleStart.position, middleEnd.position, layerMask);
rightSpot = Physics2D.Linecast(rightStart.position, rightEnd.position, layerMask);
```

Now, what I would like to do is reference the right wall (Horizontal or vertical) and calculate the distance between the wall and my sphere with:

```
Vector2.Distance(transform.position, wall1.position);
```

How can I get the reference to the correct wall to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Is the wall you're referencing coming into contact with the LineCast? If so, you'll get a reference to the object back when there's a collision.

Comment: I am not passing it to the class as a `public` variable. I am just using its layermask because I would like the same behavior for every wall

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Is the wall you want to get the distance to within the distance of the LineCast? Or are you wanting to get a reference to the nearest wall?

Comment: Don't worry, I am completely new to this. So, I might be doing things in the wrong way. leftSpot, middleSpot, and rightSpot become true whenever the left, middle, or right line touch a wall. I want to get a referenced to that touched wall and calculate the distance between that wall and the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting a [`RaycastHit2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Linecast.html) object back from your test. You can access the hit info from that to get the distance and other information about the object you hit. Something like the following:

```
RaycastHit2D leftHitInfo = Physics2D.Linecast(leftStart.position,
           leftEnd.position, layerMask);

if(leftHitInfo.collider != null) {
   Debug.Log("Left hit! Distance: " + leftHitInfo.distance.ToString());
}
```

If you're performing this test regularly, I suggest you use the [non-alloc version](http://Physics2D.LinecastNonAlloc) of this method:

```
int maxReturnedIntersections = 5;
RaycastHit2D[] hitResults = new RaycastHit2D[maxReturnedIntersections];

int hitCount = Physics2D.LinecastNonAlloc(leftStart.position, leftEnd.position, hitResults, layerMask);

if(hitCount > 0) {
    Debug.Log("Left hit! First distance: " + hitResults[0].distance.ToString());
}
```

Ideally, you'd create the array of hit results outside of your method so you're not creating a new one over and over.